# Query hangs indefinitely but components of query resolve fine

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LOOKUP_FIELD
    ,VALUE_FIELD
FROM dbo.DATA_TABLE
WHERE
    VALUE_FIELD != 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    AND LOOKUP_FIELD IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT LOOKUP_FIELD
        FROM dbo.REFERENCE_TABLE
        WHERE
            FIELD_TYPE = 0
            AND CODE IN (
                SELECT CODE
                FROM dbo.QUEUE_1
                WHERE DATETIME_ACKNOWLEDGED IS NULL
                UNION
                SELECT CODE
                FROM dbo.QUEUE_2
                WHERE DATETIME_ACKNOWLEDGED IS NULL
            )
    )
```

I am able to get every component of the query to resolve, including:

1. The innermost subquery with the UNION (10k records, ~3 seconds)
2. The second innermost subquery with the SELECT DISTINCT LOOKUP_FIELD (300 records, ~8 seconds)
3. The main query without the IN condition in the WHERE clause (35k records, ~1 second)

However, when I run the full query, it runs indefinitely. I've tried adding WITH (NOLOCK) to every table in the query but it doesn't solve the problem. I'm honestly bewildered since it seems like there are no locks on anything and every component of the query is resolving very quickly. Any hints on troubleshooting? Server version is SQL Server 2019.

Comment: For SQL performance help, we really need to see the query plan (preferably actual rather than estimated), you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, and if you want anonymize with SentryOne Plan Explorer. We also need to see table *and index* definitions. Without this info we are simply wasting our time guessing. `NOLOCK` is not a go-faster switch, it's a give-incorrect-results switch

Comment: At a guess, the top level `DISTINCT` is slowing things down, and the `UNION` in the sub-subquery is getting fully evaluated on every run of the subquery. We really need the query plans to know for sure